# Spring Dispatcher-Servlet not starting

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, model-view-controller, jakarta-ee

When I run the web application I should see some information about the dispatcher servlet in the console but I only get information about the TomCat server. The Spring dispatcher servlet never get's loaded as it should. I've tried everything for about a week now but I still could not get it working. Here is some code.

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
    id="WebApp_ID" version="3.1">

    <display-name>spring-mvc-demo</display-name>

    <!-- Spring MVC Configs -->

    <!-- Step 1: Configure Spring MVC Dispatcher Servlet -->
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>/WEB-INF/mvc-servlet.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <!-- Step 2: Set up URL mapping for Spring MVC Dispatcher Servlet -->
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    
</web-app>
```

mvc-servlet.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd">

    <!-- Step 3: Add support for component scanning -->
    <context:component-scan base-package="pack"/>

    <!-- Step 4: Add support for conversion, formatting and validation support -->
    <mvc:annotation-driven/>

    <!-- Step 5: Define Spring MVC view resolver -->
    <bean
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/view/" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </bean>

</beans>
```

The output in my console shows only info about TomCat:
[My console output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1I9A6.png)

I need to see this info message:
[Correct console output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EBNlT.jpg)

Comment: .......................

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I actually found an answer, this is very very specific problem for those who are following [this udemy course](https://www.udemy.com/course/spring-hibernate-tutorial/) from love2code.com. The problem was that the instructor used some faulty jar files that worked back when he made the tutorial but do not work today. The solution is to add the spring-web and spring-webmvc dependencies to your pom.xml. This solved my silly problem. Special Thanks to Chad Darby (udemy instructor) for wasting my time with these faulty jars.

Comment: HI. Would you tell us which version of the two libraries you used? Those dependencies are already in my pom.xml, but problem persists.

Comment: I'm using spring-webmvc version 5.3.0 dependency. Here is a link to my pom.xml
 
https://github.com/leotrimvojvoda/loginform/blob/main/pom.xml

If you still can't figure it out feel free to contact me and I'll connect to your machine  via teamViewer.

Comment: I am following same course. I was using pom.xml for dependencies, but I was not adding the spring mvc dependency. Once I added spring webmvc dependency it started working. Thanks for pointing out the issue.